# append string to src

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I need to append a sting of text "&showinfo=0" to the end of an iframe src attribute.

I have tried

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').src += "&showinfo=0";
```

but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')` will return an array containing all `iframe`s on the page, even if there is only one. You need to grab one of the items in that array before you can modify it.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src += "&showinfo=0";
//                                     ^^^ added
```

Though it may be easier to give it an id, and find it that way.

```
// <iframe id="mySnazzyFrame" src="...">
document.getElementsById('mySnazzyFrame').src += "&showinfo=0";
```

---

Oh you need to apply it to all iframes in the array? That's easy, you just loop through them, and preform the process on each one.

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
  iframes[i].src += "&showinfo=0";
}
```

Comment: I should have said I need to apply it to all the iframes so probably best to do it by class - but how?? I have managed to add a class via jQuery - so it just selecting it and appending the string...

Comment: Thanku - worked great. Been stumping me all afternoon / evening that has!

Comment: @user1683285 If you ever need to only update the iframes with a certain class you could use my answer.

Comment: @user1683285 If my post was helpful and solved your problem, please upvote (the upward triangle) and/or accept it (checkmark). That's how this website works.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
iframe.src = iframe.src + "&showinfo=0";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should see an error in your console.  `getElementsByTagName` returns an array...  try:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src+= '&showinfo=';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery anyways you probably should do it like this:

```
$(".yourClass").each( function() { 
   var oldValue = $(this).prop("src");
   $(this).prop("src", oldValue + "&showinfo=0");
});
```

This will add "&showinfo=0" to every iframe with the class "yourClass".

Hope this helps!

P.S. You might want to update your questions with the information you gave in the comments.

Comment: Brilliant - also worked great. Def will come in handy - thanks so much.

Comment: @user1683285 You're welcome! On a side note, if you up-vote/accept answers it makes it easier for other people with the same problem to find. :)